# Get json object data populated on javascript alert window

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, servlets, serialization

i have a java servlet, it does return me a serilized json object,  in the json i have data like this:

```
    brands: [
{
name: "audi",
title: "Audi",
datePublished: "23-04-2014",
lastUpdated: "15-05-2014",
logo: "/content/dam/inchcape/product-passion/brand-logos/Audi_logo.png",
countrydata: [
{
countryname: "uk",
countrytitle: "United Kingdom",
languages: [
{
name: "en",
title: "English",
datePublished: "23-04-2014",
lastUpdated: "09-01-2014",
products: [
{
name: "new-audi-a3-cabriolet",
title: "New Audi A3 Cabriolet",
datePublished: "23-04-2014",
lastUpdated: "19-05-2014",
path: "/content/inchcape/product-passion/uk/audi/en/new-audi-a3-cabriolet"
}
],
archivedProducts: [ ]
}
]
}
]
},
```

now what i m trying to do is to get these data write out on an alert using javascript, here is my code...

```
var jsonDataForBrands;

function changeBrand(){
    var builder = 'jsonDataForBrands has:\n';
    for (field in jsonDataForBrands) {
        builder += field + ' = ' + jsonDataForBrands[field] + '\n';
    }
    alert(builder);
}

$(function () {
    $.ajax('/bin/public/inchcape/product-passion/available-brands', {
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        jsonDataForBrands = data;

        changeBrand();
    });
});
```

any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess you forget to parse jsonDataForBrands = JSON.parse(data);

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax('/bin/public/inchcape/product-passion/available-brands', {
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        jsonDataForBrands = JSON.parse(data);

        changeBrand();
    });
});
```

Comment: it s complaning:    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o   ,any suggestions?